# How to make a key optional?

Tags: typescript

here is the code:

```
type TypeKey = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type Types = { [key in TypeKey] : string}

let myTypes : Types = {
    A : 'Apple',
    B : 'Banna'
}
```

this will have an error:

```
error: TS2741 [ERROR]: Property 'C' is missing in type '{ A: string; B: string; }' but required in type 'Types'.
```

How to make 'C' optional? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way, but you can do it by removing `C` from the type and then adding it back as an optional property:

```
type TypeKey = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
// Remove C  vvvvv−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−vvvvvv
type Types = Omit<{ [key in TypeKey] : string}, 'C'> & {C?: string}
// Add it back as an optional property −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

let myTypes : Types = {
    A : 'Apple',
    B : 'Banna'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGkIigXigcgIIagH0wCFcCMBhDAKAHpqoAlCAWwHsA3aMqKN33wJCJBQ4SNFi+fSqEix4AZzRQA8kwCWwADwBvKAG0A1siiqAdrMhIQAXSgAuKHOAAnUwHMAvgBpMFAHxQAMigtMgB+e0cXEw8aOiwAE3jjYCgAIwBDAGN9KHSFdLMWMGBVFhN0gBsoMCciiCdQKDExAD029o6OykoKiBSmEDhIBXshiAV0LUpubiw7TCwwMF6MT2mZwnmMQgLyqndKIA)

---

In a comment you've asked:

> it works, but any better way? something like `type TypeKey = 'A' | 'B' | 'C?'`

Not as far as I know, but you can turn this on its head and define `TypeKey` in terms of `Types` rather than the other way around:

```
interface Types {
    A: string;
    B: string;
    C?: string;
}

type TypeKey = keyof Types;

let myTypes : Types = {
    A : 'Apple',
    B : 'Banna'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDOyDeAUMicgIIBcyOYUoA5gNzGkBCVNdITLJAwgH4OtBswC+hQmCwoM2ANIR0yALzIA1koD2MNDJzNCAGwhhkAW3RzcyKtbxqipcreQByMpkwm3AGl7IrK5urHAgIHBuhBJAA)

Comment: it works, but any better way? something like type TypeKey = 'A' | 'B' | 'C?'

Comment: @sqllyw - I've replied to that comment by adding to the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in more generic fashion as below:

```js
type TypeKey = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type Types = { [key in TypeKey]: string }

type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>

const myTypes: Optional<Types, 'C'> = {
  A: 'Apple',
  B: 'Banna'
}
```